# Any function on the framework with return type overloading?

Tags: .net, types, return, overloading

Had the idea I'd seen at least one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's supported by the common language runtime (CLR) but not by the .NET languages that Microsoft has included in Visual Studio. The only .NET "language" that currently supports this is IL. I'm not aware of any functions in the framework which exhibit this, but even if there were there they would not be common language specification (CLS) compliant. Read Richter's excellent .NET book for more information.

EDIT: A good example is conversion operators. Where there exists an explicit or implicit conversion of a type to more than one other data type, these will be compiled into IL as methods differing only in their return types.

Comment: I am aware of that. Just had the idea I'd seen one.

Comment: Does it mean that by not being CLS compliant, in the case I'd make a function on IL with return type overloading, I couldn't use it in c#?